# grub error: file not found

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I reboot my debian server and now  grub is telling me this:

```
error: file not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescuse>
```

ls will show this:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Now i'm executing ls for each item:

```
> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem

> ls (hd0,msdos2)/
error: unknown filesystem

> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ lost+found/ var/ etc/ media/ sbin/ usr/ lib/ lib64/ boot/ bin/ tmp/ root/ mmt/ home/ dev/ proc/  selinux/ sys/ srv/ opt/ lib32/
```

Not i'm seting the root to

```
> set root="(hd0,msdos1)"
```

and the prefix to

```
> set prefix="(hd0,msdos1)/boot"
```

but `>insmod normal` tells me: `error: file not found`

when i'm tring to set the prefix to `(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub` i've got the same error...

whats wrong?

Comment: Those commands are correct for booting in BIOS-Legacy mode. Are you sure you are not on UEFI?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes...